# how do I log messages using winston and passport session

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, logging, winston

I am using winston logger. I had to use the https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-winston because I wanted `req` object to use the `user.id`.

I want to create a log file for each user. This is a B-to-B application and the number of users will be less, so, I am sure the number of files won't explode.

This is my winston middleware implementation-

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  expressWinston.logger({
    // winstonInstance: global.logger,
    transports: [
      new winston.transports.Console(),
      //all logs
      new winston.transports.File({
        filename: `${logPath}/fapi-logs-${mmyyyy}.log`,
        format: winston.format.json(),
      }),
      //all logs per user
      new winston.transports.File({
        filename: `${logPath}/fapi-logs-${mmyyyy}-user-${req.session.user.id}.log`,
        format: winston.format.json(),
      }),
      //warnings - no data for keywords
      new winston.transports.File({
        level: "warn",
        filename: `${logPath}/fapi-warn-${mmyyyy}.log`,
        format: winston.format.json(),
      }),
      //warnings - no data for keywords
      new winston.transports.File({
        level: "debug",
        filename: `${logPath}/fapi-debug-${mmyyyy}.log`,
        format: winston.format.json(),
      }),
      //server errors
      new winston.transports.File({
        level: "error",
        filename: `${logPath}/fapi-error-${mmyyyy}.log`,
        format: winston.format.json(),
      }),
    ], //this is ignored as winstonInstance is provided
    format: winston.format.combine(
      winston.format.colorize(),
      winston.format.json(),
      winston.format.timestamp(),
      winston.format.prettyPrint()
    ),
    meta: true, // optional: control whether you want to log the meta data about the request (default to true)
    httpinfo:
      "HTTP userid-{{req.session}} | statusCode-{{res.statusCode}} | url-{{req.url}} | method-{{req.method}} | responseTime-{{res.responseTime}}ms", // optional: customize the default logging message. E.g. "{{res.statusCode}} {{req.method}} {{res.responseTime}}ms {{req.url}}"
    expressFormat: true, // Use the default Express/morgan request formatting. Enabling this will override any msg if true. Will only output colors with colorize set to true
    colorize: true, // Color the text and status code, using the Express/morgan color palette (text: gray, status: default green, 3XX cyan, 4XX yellow, 5XX red).
    ignoreRoute: function (req, res) {
      return false;
    }, // optional: allows to skip some log messages based on request and/or response
  });
  next();
});
```

How do I log to files? I mean, `console.log` is not logging to the files. The files are created though, but, nothing is written to the file.

I tried using `logger.info` as well in my routes files and other `.js` files, it threw an error saying `logger is not defined`.

Please can you tell me what I am missing?

Comment: what is issue with loog in same file and accumulate base of user id

Comment: I dont think, creating a different log for the different users is a good solution.

Comment: @xdeepakv ok. sure, let us say I remove the per user log. How do I still see logs? I am not getting logs even in the other log files which contain all user data. I tried using - `console.log`(nothing is printing) and `logger.info`(throwing an error that logger is undefined).

Comment: you are mising log with data base. If user remove it doesn't mean you should remove log. in u case it make more sense to use database. You will have better control. You can write middleware to write on database.